# Formatting bash errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stderr

I am using Fedora 14 and when I am executing a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
asd #assuming this command does not exist
```

I am getting following error:
`/path/to/file: line 2: asd: command not found`

I want to format it so it outputs error in same way as it would when it was executed from terminal:

```
$ asd
bash: asd: command not found
```

Comment: I am trying to fathom **why** exactly you would not want to know where the error is coming from...

Comment: [ScreenShot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10530011/obrazki/screeny/e2cmdshell.png) - I am making kind of terminal in-game and I am using script to execute the file with given interval. (when I mistyped `pwd` as `pd` long error showed up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe this example would help you. Here is the script content:

```
#!/bin/bash

fun() {
    echo "Error trapped"
}

trap fun ERR

asd
```

And here is how you should call it:

```
$ ./so.sh 2> /dev/null
```

The result is:

```
Error trapped
```

The signal ERR is trapped every time a command returns non-zero.